# How can drop rows there are any specifc value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this values in a column:

```
['AUTOMÓVEL', 'RESIDÊNCIA', 'VIDA', nan, 'SAÚDE', 'EMPRESA','RE - PORTATEIS', 'CONDOMÍNIO', 
'OUTROS', 'SEGURO VIAGEM','CARRO FACIL']
```

How can drop rows there are any specifc value?
For Example, i need drop ['AUTOMÓVEL', 'RESIDÊNCIA', 'VIDA']

I tried:

```
df.drop(df.index[df['myvar'] == ['AUTOMÓVEL', 'RESIDÊNCIA', 'VIDA']], inplace = True)
```

No success

Comment: you  use `DataFrame.drop` when you've got indices to use... otherwise when you have column values, have you tried, `new_df = df[~df['myvar'].isin(['AUTOMÓVEL', 'RESIDÊNCIA', 'VIDA'])]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .isin() method like this

```
new_df = df[~df['myvar'].isin(['AUTOMÓVEL', 'RESIDÊNCIA', 'VIDA'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

```
df=df.drop(df[df.myvar.isin(['AUTOMÓVEL', 'RESIDÊNCIA', 'VIDA'])].index)
df.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
li = ['AUTOMÓVEL', 'RESIDÊNCIA', 'VIDA',np.nan, 'SAÚDE', 'EMPRESA','RE - PORTATEIS', 'CONDOMÍNIO', 'OUTROS', 'SEGURO VIAGEM','CARRO FACIL']
to_excl = ['AUTOMÓVEL', 'RESIDÊNCIA', 'VIDA']
```

```
df_filtered = df[~df['col_values_are_in'].isin(to_excl)]
```

Which will give you a new dataframe without the rows that include the values in the list you want to exclude.